# The surface of the last scattering and pictures of deep field

Tags: astronomy, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background, observable-universe

Maybe this question (in fact I have a few of them) is naive but nevertheless, let me try to ask it: it is concerning the furthest regions of our universe.

> Is the Hubble telescope capable to observe the image of the surface of the last scattering? If not-will the James Webb Telescope be able to observe it? Imagine some picture like an extreme deep field (which was taken by Hubble telescope) which actually reach to the surface of the last scattering: how this surface would be visible in this picture? And finally-what happens when the time passes-since the surface of the last scattering is receding from us-would we be able to observe some new galactics, previously unseen for us?

Comment: Isn't the cosmic microwave background the last scattering surface?

Comment: The cosmic microwave background is present everywhere and is only visible in microwaves due to the cooling of the universe. The surface of the last scattering is in fact the cosmic microwave background but from the time around 300.000 years after Big Bang when the universe became transparent (not opaque)-remember, looking into far distance you're looking back in time.

Answer (score 2):

Hubble observes in the optical and JWST will observe in the infrared, so neither can observe the surface of last scattering, which is a microwave background.

The CMB does get redshifted as time passes but so too does every other distant object, so rather than more galaxies becoming observable as time passes, there will actually be fewer. If dark energy continues to dominate, one day there will be no galaxies visible at all.